# Múltiples ventanas de Selenium con python y repetir el ciclo

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Un código en Python para automatizar unas pruebas y rendimiento en base a Selenium y un portal web.
El código funciona bien, sin embargo me abre solo una ventana del navegador y debo abrirlo y cerrarlo manualmente.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para decirle cuántas ventanas quiero abrir al mismo tiempo (*variable QtyBrowser*)?
y ¿Cuántas veces quiero que me repita ese proceso (*variable repetición*)?

Adjunto código en Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from random import randint
from time import sleep
import os
import time
import random

proxy = random.choice(open('proxies.txt').readlines())
useragent = random.choice(open('useragents.txt').readlines())
url = "https://wwww.angelesmedia.net/"

qtyBrowser = input("¿Cuántos navegadores quieres abrir?")
repeticion = input("¿Cuantas veces quieres repetir ese proceso?")

opts1 = Options()
opts1.add_argument('--user-agent=%s'% useragent)
opts1.add_argument('--incognito')
opts1.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s'% proxy)
opts1.add_argument('--start-maximized')
browser1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts1)
browser1.execute_script("window.location.replace(arguments[0])", url)
time.sleep(10)
with open('credentials.txt') as f:
    credentials = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in f]
for username, password in credentials:
    browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="login-username"] """).send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="login-password"] """).send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(2)
    submit = browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/label """)
    submit.click()
    submit = browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="login-button"] """)
    submit.click()
    time.sleep(15)
    play_button = browser1.find_element_by_xpath(""" //*[@id="main"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section/div[3]/div/button[1] """)
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(randint(180,3200))
    browser1.quit()
# Final del script de login
```

Gracias de antemano.

**Nota:** Soy muy nuevo en python. Acepto mejoras del código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré tu pregunta mientras buscaba otra relacionada a Selenium.

Primero que nada, para abrir y cerrar el navegador en Selenium usamos driver.get(string_de_la_url) y driver.close(). En este caso el driver sería browser1.

No es posible abrir varios navegadores a la vez con Selenium, pero hay una solución.

Puedes importar el módulo threading, y crear threads, los threads hace que un procedimiento o método se ejecute varias veces a la misma vez. Entonces puedes abrir varios navegadores al mismo tiempo.

Para implementar esto, debes meter la parte de tu código que abre, trabaja y cierra el navegador dentro de un método, supongamos que esta función se llama abrir_navegador(credenciales, browser). El código para instanciar varios threads que se ejecutarán al mismo tiempo sería el siguiente:

```
def abrir_navegador(credenciales, browser):
...



### Creamos las opciones para enviarle
opts1 = Options()
opts1.add_argument('--user-agent=%s'% useragent)
opts1.add_argument('--incognito')
opts1.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s'% proxy)
opts1.add_argument('--start-maximized')

### Creamos los navegadores
navegadores = []
for _ in range(qtyBrowser):
    navegadores.append(webdriver.Chrome(options=opts1))



### Instanciando varios hilos (threads)
hilos = []
### Esto inicia todos los threads
for i in range(qtyBrowser):
        
    t = threading.Thread(target=abrir_navegador, args = [tus_credenciales, navegadores[i]])
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
### Esto hace que tu programa espere a que se terminen de ejecutar los threads para continuar
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Si tienes dudas recomiendo que te informes sobre threading y procesos

Comment: millón e gracias. Eso era, multihilo!! Estudié un poco sobre eso, hice algunos ajustes y lo adapte a lo que necesitaba.!! Fue excelente! Lo mejor!